# Clear DataGrid data in WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, itemssource

Because I want have checkbox column, I use this way create checkbox
in my XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="boxNoDetail" IsReadOnly="true" ItemsSource="{Binding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontSize="12"  >
    <DataGrid.Columns >
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Checked"   Binding="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  >
                  <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                         <Style TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type CheckBox}}"  >
                                    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                                    <Setter Property="IsHitTestVisible" Value="False"/>
                                                                    <!--'read only-->
                                                                </Style>
                   </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
         </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

I use this way to bind gridview:

```
  Function dtFillDatagrid(ByVal dt As DataTable, ByVal dgv As DataGrid) As Boolean
        dgv.ItemsSource = nothing
        Dim myUI As userInterface = New userInterface

        Try
            For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                Dim name As String = column.ColumnName
                If name = "IsSelected" Then
                ElseIf name = "sn" Then
                    dgv.Columns.Add(myUI.DataGridText(name, name, True))            
                Else
                    dgv.Columns.Add(myUI.DataGridText(name, name))
                End If

            Next
            dgv.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView
            dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            dgv.CanUserAddRows = False
            Return True
        Catch ex As Exception
            logUtil.e(ex)
            Return False
        End Try

    End Function


Public Class userInterface
Function DataGridText(ByVal bind_name As String, ByVal headerName As String, 
                      Optional notVisible As Boolean = False, 
                      Optional rightAlignment As Boolean = False) As DataGridTextColumn
        Dim col_data As DataGridTextColumn = New DataGridTextColumn
        Dim c As New Style
        col_data.Binding = New Binding(bind_name)
        col_data.Header = headerName
        If notVisible Then col_data.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden
        If rightAlignment Then
            c.Setters.Add(New Setter(TextBox.TextAlignmentProperty, TextAlignment.Right))
            col_data.CellStyle = c
        End If
        Return col_data
    End Function
end class
```

If I refresh the data (by running `dtFillDatagrid()` again), the datagrid's columns are displayed 2 times. Why ???

I tried to detect step by step, and found that dgv.Itemssource = Nothing is just clear gridview data, and there is no clear field.

I want to ask, how can I use DTFILLDATAGRID() repeatedly and solve the problem of rduplicate columns, or is it more convenient for DataTable Fill to gridView?

first load gridview:
[image]

second load gridview:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you specify `dgv.AutoGenerateColumns = False`, the columns will be specified manually which you are doing in:

1. The XAML: DataGrid.Columns. Here you create the first column, a DataGridCheckBoxColumn.
2. In `dtFillDatagrid` where add new columns using your `DataGridText` function.

You only need to define the columns once. In your current code, you are adding DataGridTextColumns every time `dtFillDatagrid` executes:

`dgv.Columns.Add(myUI.DataGridText(name, name))`

You should adjust the code to create the columns once in a separate subroutine when your Window initializes.

If the columns in your DataTable (`dt.Columns`) potentially **change every time** you run `dtFillDatagrid`, then you can remove all the columns except the `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` (by checking the column's Header value) and then add the new columns like you are doing now. Just add this code to `dtFillDatagrid`, before adding columns again:

```
Dim columnsToRemove As New List(Of DataGridColumn)
For Each column As DataGridColumn In boxNoDetail.Columns
    If column.Header <> "Checked" Then
        columnsToRemove.Add(column)
    End If
Next
For Each column As DataGridColumn In columnsToRemove
    boxNoDetail.Columns.Remove(column)
Next
```